# Sentence condensers

Tags: gerunds, present-participles

I got an assignment for my linguistics class, but I don´t understand what it means.

> Search through the text and find examples of present and past participles, infinitives and gerunds used as **sentence condensers**

Can please someone give me an example, where are the participles, gerunds or infinitives used as **sentence condensers**?

Comment: Answering this question could take a very long time since it is rather broad, and it would be better asked on a site devoted to linguistics. This site is about learning how to use the English language.

Answer (score 2):

It took a little research to answer this, since the expression "Sentence condenser" is rarely used in English. It appears to be common in Czech linguistics.

When a text is rephrased so that an independent or coordinate clause (containing a finite verb) is replaced by a gerund, participle or infinitive, the verb so reduced is said to be a sentence condenser. Thus:

> She opened the door and started to sing  *becomes*
>   
>   Opening the door, she started to sing.

The finite clause "she opened the door" becomes the participle phrase "Opening the door".

> He eats lots of fruit, which is good for his health. *becomes*
>   
>   Eating lots of fruit is good for his health

(This example uses a gerund)

If you can take a sentence that uses a gerund, participle or infinitive, and rephrase it using finite clauses, then you have found a sentence condenser.

sources

[syntax of -ing forms in legal English](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=I3rVBbQ2QHoC&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=SENTENCE+CONDENSERS&source=bl&ots=lj56jnZ2M-&sig=GWC_fPEu_hFlLnxwsocI9YwRkIk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXsIqetKnbAhXKLMAKHeHsBF44ChDoAQgoMAA#v=onepage&q=SENTENCE%20CONDENSERS&f=false)

[reference grammar and modern linguistic theory](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pTC16PpEiVIC&pg=PA268&lpg=PA268&dq=SENTENCE+CONDENSERS&source=bl&ots=F_VOtvDCq_&sig=PUMMYd99KRHXbuz2_mnZUfC57MM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXsIqetKnbAhXKLMAKHeHsBF44ChDoAQgtMAI#v=onepage&q=SENTENCE%20CONDENSERS&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

Basically these are structures used in English to make a sentence shorter, including ellipsis, short passive, substitution, verbless clauses and also non-finite clauses (gerunds, participles and to-infinitives - non-finite structures are intended to be SENTENCE condensers and not just condensers since the process includes the whole clause). I am from the Czech republic and this term tend to be used here, I dont know why.. it is funny.